# SQL server query running extremely slow

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

The following query is being used to create a pie within a business intelligence dashboard. The query runs and returns the correct data, however it is extremely slow (about 36 seconds). Can anyone see a way to optimize this query?

```
SELECT 
Name,
Date,
Severity,
PMissing


FROM
(
SELECT
Name,
Date,
Severity,
PMissing,

DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ate DESC) AS Rnk

FROM PctbyP

WHERE (Name like '%front-%'
OR Name like '%back-%'
OR Name like '%ap-%'
OR Name like '%mps-%'
OR Name like '%mg-%')
)t
WHERE rnk=1
AND PMissing != '0'
```

Comment: How many records are in the table and how many are returned?

Comment: There are 816,144 records in the table and the query returns 21. I have no read/write access to this table. The table stores automatic scan results.

Comment: Searching like this: `like '%front-%'` (`LIKE` with a leading `%`) is guaranteed to avoid any indices you might have and will be slow and getting slower with each additional row in the table ...

Comment: if you commented out the `Name` conditions, how many records would the query return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an indexed view:

```
CREATE VIEW
        V_PctbyP_Name
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT  Name, COUNT_BIG(*) AS Cnt
FROM    dbo.PctbyP
GROUP BY
        Name

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX
        UX_V_PctbyP_Name
ON      V_PctbyP_Name (Name)
```

, then create an index on the table:

```
CREATE INDEX
        IX_PctbyP_Name_Date
ON      PctbyP (Name, [Date])
```

, then use this query:

```
SELECT  pa.*
FROM    V_PctbyP_Name vp
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 WITH TIES
                Name, [Date], Severity, PMissing
        FROM    PctbyP p
        WHERE   p.Name = vp.Name
        ORDER BY
                [Date] DESC
        ) pa
WHERE   (
        vp.Name LIKE '%front-%'
        OR
        vp.Name LIKE '%back-%'
        OR
        vp.Name LIKE '%ap-%'
        OR
        vp.Name LIKE '%mps-%'
        OR
        vp.Name LIKE '%mg-%'
        )
        AND pa.PMissing <> '0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing a pattern match on the text column in the form %pattern% forces a scan of all records matching the outer WHERE condition (if there were an index on Name, it could not be used anyhow).

I would hazard a guess that your WHERE criteria are not very selective, meaning that a good number of rows from the table are being scanned to see if they do match the LIKE criteria.

If my assumptions are true, you may see a significant performance improvement by using full text search rather than LIKE

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

> LIKE query against a large amount of unstructured text data is much slower than an equivalent full-text query against the same data. A LIKE query against millions of rows of text data can take minutes to return; whereas a full-text query can take only seconds or less against the same data, depending on the number of rows that are returned.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx#like

Comment: I tried this and received the error "Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view because it is not full-text indexed'